# How to check if case-insensitive substring exist in the string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am trying to match a case-insensitive substring within a string, and if it gets a match, print the object to the console; but it isn't being printed. How can I use a RegEx to see if the case-insensitive substring is present in the string?

main.js

```
   function getModelData(data){
        window.activePath = "Member/Details"
        $.each(data.children, function(id, item){
            // item.name would be string like "@SDK/core/interface/member/Details";
            if (item.name.test(window.activePath)) {
            // if (path.includes(window.activePath)) {
                    console.log('OBJ', item);       
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `test` is a RegExp method.  `path` is a string.  [MDN RegExp test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: @Taplar any idea how to get expected result i also tried str.includes didnt work

Comment: You're not using anything in the data that you're looping over in the test.

Comment: `path` does not include your active path.  There is a case difference with `Member` and `member`

Comment: `"@SDK/core/interface/member/Details".includes("member/Details")` works fine

Comment: @Talpar updated question for more understanding , also is there way to use includes to check both lower/upper case values

Comment: just lowercase both inputs

Comment: `item.name.toLowerCase().includes(window.activePath.toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `item.name.includes()`.

If you need it to be case-insensitive, convert both strings to lowercase before searching.

```js
window.activePath = "Member/details";

function getModelData(data) {
  let activePath = window.activePath.toLowerCase();
  $.each(data.children, function(id, item) {
    // item.name would be string like "@SDK/core/interface/member/Details";
    if (item.name.toLowerCase().includes(activePath)) {
      console.log('OBJ', item);
    }
  });
}

var data = {
  children: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "@digital_care/combinator-interfaces/dist/SpecialtyInterfaces/Interface/Details.Model"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "@SDK/core/interface/member/Details"
  }]
};

getModelData(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Vandesh I lowercased `activePath` when assigning it. It doesn't need to be done every time through the loop.

Comment: In case `window.activePath` is being programatically read, and this is just a sample here, better to do it programatically than hardcode to lowercase value.

Comment: Good point. I set a local variable to the lowercase version of it.

Comment: for some reason its not happening for me its not printing console statment never reaching there

Comment: @Barmar thats how i am getting the `item.name` `"@digital_care/combinator-interfaces/dist/SpecialtyInterfaces/Interface/Details.Model"`

Comment: Do you think its becuase of special character ?

Comment: That doesn't have `Member/details`, it has `Interface/Details`.

Comment: I updated my answer with an executable snippet showing that it works.

Comment: thank i think i got the idea let me take it from here , thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = "test regex search 3test";
var searchKey = /\d/;
console.log(test.search(searchKey));
```

> 18